# Probability of drawing same number twice in two lottery games

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I set up a "lottery" which will have only two games as follows.

I have bucket with $N$ balls. I draw $M$ individually numbered balls from this bucket (without replacement). Then I replace all the balls and do the same procedure - i.e. another $M$ draws without replacement.

What is the probability that I will draw at least one of the balls twice?

(Obviously $M < N/2$ or else the probability would have to be 1)

How about if I generalize to 3 games? Or $K$ games? What is the probability then that the same ball is pulled in each game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are ${{N}\choose{M}}$ ways to select $M$ balls in the first turn. The probability of selecting at least one of the balls twice equals 1 minus the probability of selecting no ball twice. If we are not allowed to select the same ball twice in the second game, we must choose $M$ balls out of the remaining $N-M$ balls which have not been selected in the first game. As such, the probability to select at least one ball twice equals:

$$1 - \frac{{{N-M}\choose{M}}}{{{N}\choose{M}}} = 1 - \frac{(N-M)!^2}{N!\,(N-2M)!}$$

You can also look at it this way. On the first turn of the second game, the probability of selecting a new ball equals $\frac{N-M}{N}$. On the second turn this probability equals $\frac{N-M-1}{N-1}$, given a successful first turn. As such, the probability of selecting $M$ new balls in the second game equals:

$$\frac{N-M}{N} \cdot \frac{N-M-1}{N-1} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{N-2M+1}{N-M+1} = \frac{\frac{(N-M)!}{(N-2M)!}}{\frac{(N)!}{(N-M)!}} = \frac{(N-M)!^2}{N!\,(N-2M)!}$$