# Expected number of balls that appear at least m times among n drawings of the same lottery?

Tags: combinatorics

Imagine I have a bucket with $b$ individually numbered balls. Then I draw $d$ balls from this bucket. I repeat this drawing $n$ times, replacing the balls between each drawing (that is, between each drawing of $d$ balls, not each drawing of a single ball).

What is the expected number of balls that were drawn at least $m$ times, where $m \le n$?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2251464/617653) is similar, but it is constrained to where $n = 2$ and $m = 2$, and asks for the probability that the answer to my question is at least $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think about this in terms of the individual balls $B_i$ as random variable which take value $1$ if selected and value $0$ otherwise. For a particular ball $B_i$ the probability of selecting it on any draw is $\frac{{ b-1 \choose d-1 }}{{b \choose d }} = d/b$. Then the probability of selecting $B_i$ exactly $k$ times ( so $\sum B_i = k$) in your n draws is ${n \choose k}(d/b)^k(1-d/b)^{n-k}$, as the draws are independent. So the probability of drawing $B_i$ at least $m$ times is $P(\sum B_i \geq m)= \sum_{k=m}^{n}{n \choose k}(d/b)^k(1-d/b)^{n-k}$. Then probability of $r$ of the $B_i$ drawn at least $m$ times is then ${b \choose r}P(\sum B_i \geq 
m)^r(1-P(\sum B_i \geq m))^{b-r}$. Therefore, the expected number of balls drawn at least $m$ times is $\sum_{r=1}^b r{b \choose r}P(\sum B_i \geq m)^r(1-P(\sum B_i \geq m))^{b-r} = bP(\sum B_i \geq m)$, where this last equality follows as it is the expectation of binomial random variable.